# Trying to optimize code for simulating a Magnetically trapped electron

Tags: python, parallel-processing, physics

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Gl3.png)

I am a bit confused on what to do about scanning parameter space and would like an opinion on the course of action I should take. The code below is my attempt at it while trying to use multiprocessing to speed up the computation.

```py
def simulate_electron_motion(params):
    r0, v0, theta_max = params
    # Initial conditions
    x0 = r0
    y0 = 0
    z0 = 0
    vx0 = v0 * np.sin(theta_max)
    vy0 = 0
    vz0 = v0 * np.cos(theta_max)
    
    initial_conditions = [x0, vx0, y0, vy0, z0, vz0]
    
    # Time span for simulation
    t_span = (0, 5e-9) 
    
    # Solving the ODEs numerically
    sol = solve_ivp(ODE, t_span, initial_conditions, method='RK45', dense_output=True)
    
    # Extracting the solution
    t = np.linspace(0, sol.t[-1], 10)
    sol_traj = sol.sol(t)
    
    # Finding the bounce frequency (1 / (2 times return time))
    bounce_times = [t[i] for i in range(1, len(t)-1) if sol_traj[5, i-1] > 0 and sol_traj[5, i] <= 0]
    bounce_frequencies = [1 / (2 * (bounce_times[i] - bounce_times[i-1])) for i in range(1, len(bounce_times))]
    
    return bounce_frequencies, r0, np.degrees(theta_max)

def parallel_simulation(param_combinations):
    if __name__='__main__':
        with Pool() as pool:
            results = pool.map(simulate_electron_motion, param_combinations)
    return results

v0 = np.sqrt(2 * 18.6e3 * e / m_e) 
theta_max_values = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 89, 10))  # Maximum emission angle in radians
r0_values = np.linspace(0, 0.024, 10)

param_combinations = [(r0, v0, theta_max) for r0 in r0_values for theta_max in theta_max_values]
```